# SPARQL: Equivalent of SQL UPDATE?

Tags: sql, sql-update, sparql

I was wondering if SPARQL had an equivalent of the SQL "update" query? Where would I find a tutorial for it for beginners?

Answer (score 7):

Yes – [SPARQL Update](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/), new in SPARQL 1.1. I highly recommend Bob DuCharme's [Learning SPARQL](http://www.learningsparql.com/) book. I'm not aware of any good beginner's tutorials, but if you know how to query data with SPARQL, then the examples in the SPARQL Update specification should help you to get started.